# Action is not returning a single value

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework2

It seems to be an easy one but I am not able to manage an ajax post vor validation.

Via Ajax post I am sending data to an validation-action. so far so far so good.

the next step is returning a single value. Here is the problem. My action doesn't return the value.

Here is the action

```
public function solveEquationAction(){
    $riddle = new Question();
    $request = $this->getRequest()->getPost()->get('equation');
    return $riddle->solveEquation($request);
}
```

Here is my ajax post

```
function validateAnswer(answer){
    var equation = jQuery('#riddleAnswer').text();

    $.ajax({
        url : '/riddle/solveequation',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'equation': equation},
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            console.log(data);
        },
    //...
    });
}
```

I need the action to return only the solved equation so I can check it in the succes-part in my ajax post

Thanks in advance

Comment: switch the `return` to `echo` or `print` :)

Comment: Your action does `return` value, but if you want to get it as ajax response you need to `echo` it instead.

Comment: i tried already. the console.log(data) ist still printing out the complete HTML-code not just the value i need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd better use `ViewJsonStrategy` here.

```
public function indexAction()
{
   $riddle = new Question();
   $request = $this->getRequest()->getPost()->get('equation');

   return new \Zend\View\Model\JsonModel(array(
       'result'  => $riddle->solveEquation($request),
       'success' => true
   ));
}
```

**[Read more.](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/returning-json-from-a-zf2-controller-action/)**

Comment: tried it also with jsonmodel. leads to fatal error: class Zend\ViewModel\JsonModel not found

Comment: You need to add this line `use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;` at the top after namespace & before class

Comment: +1 @wurmi the namespace had a missing `\\` which has now been corrected; this is the method you should be using